# maven Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport

Tags: java, maven, build, wsimport

Below is my pom.xml for to do wsimport

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.dat</groupId>
  <artifactId>digsig</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>digsig</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-xjc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>    
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</outputDirectory>
              <silent>true</silent>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2.7</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2.9</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <!-- Following configuration will pass all XML files from ${basedir}/src/bindings to wsimport. -->
            <configuration>
              <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src</bindingDirectory>
              <vmArgs>
                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
              </vmArgs>
              <wsdlUrls>
                <wsdlUrl>http://webservice.server/Services/InvoiceService.asmx?WSDL</wsdlUrl>
              </wsdlUrls>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Build is failing with below error

```
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:jar:2.3
[DEBUG]   Included: com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:jar:2.2.8
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:0.6.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.6.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.6.4
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser:jar:1.0.8
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.10
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) bindingDirectory = D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\src
[DEBUG]   (f) destDir = D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) extension = false
[DEBUG]   (f) genJWS = false
[DEBUG]   (f) implDestDir = D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\src\main\java
[DEBUG]   (f) keep = true
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///c:/tools/maven/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (f) pluginArtifactMap = {org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin=org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.3:, com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools=com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:jar:2.2.8:compile, org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics=org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:0.6.4:compile, org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime=org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.6.4:compile, org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools=org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.6.4:compile, commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils=commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile, commons-lang:commons-lang=commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.2:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging=commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile, com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser=com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser:jar:1.0.8:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-project=org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-settings=org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-profile=org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-model=org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager=org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata=org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent=backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry=org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact=org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile, junit:junit=junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile, classworlds:classworlds=classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api=org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.5:compile, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus=org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4:compile, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean=org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0:compile, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice=org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava=org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.10:compile}
[DEBUG]   (f) quiet = false
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [      id: nexus
      url: http://passport-nexus/nexus/content/groups/public
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => never]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) settings = org.apache.maven.execution.SettingsAdapter@78e89bfe
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDestDir = D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\target\generated-sources\wsimport
[DEBUG]   (f) staleFile = D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\target\jaxws\stale
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) vmArgs = [-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all]
[DEBUG]   (f) wsdlDirectory = D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\src\wsdl
[DEBUG]   (f) wsdlUrls = [http://webservice.server/Services/InvoiceService.asmx?WSDL]
[DEBUG]   (f) xadditionalHeaders = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xdebug = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xdisableAuthenticator = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xdisableSSLHostnameVerification = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xnoAddressingDataBinding = false
[DEBUG]   (f) xnocompile = true
[DEBUG]   (f) xuseBaseResourceAndURLToLoadWSDL = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.dat:digsig:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\pom.xml
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] The wsdl Directory is D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\src\wsdl
[DEBUG] The binding Directory is D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\src
[INFO] Processing: http://webservice.server/Services/InvoiceService.asmx?WSDL
[DEBUG] adding src root: D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\target\generated-sources\wsimport
[DEBUG] The binding Directory is D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\src
[DEBUG] jaxws:wsimport args: [-keep, -s, D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\target\generated-sources\wsimport, -d, D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\target\classes, -encoding, UTF-8, -Xnocompile]
[INFO] jaxws:wsimport args: [-keep, -s, D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\target\generated-sources\wsimport, -d, D:\Dev\Eclipse_Workspace\Neon\WebService_Demo\digsig\target\classes, -encoding, UTF-8, -Xnocompile, "http://webservice.server/Services/InvoiceService.asmx?WSDL"]
[DEBUG] dummy:dummy:jar:1.0 (selected for null)
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for com.sun.xml.ws:project:pom:2.2.8
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for com.sun.xml.ws:bundles:pom:2.2.8
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:pom:2.2.8
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:jar:2.2.8, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${tools.jar} @ com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri-bom:2.2.8, c:\tools\maven\repository\com\sun\xml\ws\jaxws-ri-bom\2.2.8\jaxws-ri-bom-2.2.8.pom, line 395, column 29

[DEBUG]   com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:jar:2.2.8:compile (selected for compile)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.747 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-27T16:47:38-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/364M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default) on project digsig: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default) on project digsig: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(Unknown Source)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.getCP(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:484)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.exec(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:359)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.WsImportMojo.processWsdlViaUrls(WsImportMojo.java:342)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.WsImportMojo.execute(WsImportMojo.java:282)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.jaxws.MainWsImportMojo.execute(MainWsImportMojo.java:50)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: can u try to add this repository https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons/jaxws-maven-plugin in pom.xml file ?

Comment: i just added the plugin to my test pom.xml file, i think the problem come from files your using not in maven plugin itslef.

Comment: In your settings.xml, do you have any dependency management with a value of ${tools.jar} ?

Comment: @RanPaul, have you got any solution? I am facing exactly same issue.

Comment: @PriyankaW I fiixed it using Gradle instead of Maven

Comment: @RanPaul thanks for update. I am looking for maven based solution.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this error by simply downgrading the JDK version I was using. 
Right-click on your project > Properties > Build > Compile > Java Platform > Set it to JDK 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it will happen because of a class not found exception.

1. click wsgen error and then you can see more details
2. check from which point the build failed
3. Check the class in sei tag (in pom.xml) refers to the correct service. it should point the correct path from the source(src).

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting JDK 17 then you can just replace

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            ...
```

with

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            ...
```

Reload the POM and recompile.

I'm looking for a way to update the NetBeans 18

> New file > Web Service > Web Service Client

template so I don't have to mangle the pom.xml manually.